# Add a filter and a filter as a consequence in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
df_example <- data.frame(id = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7"),
                         amount = c(12,13,15,12,12,15,18),
                         flag = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
                         upg = c(NA,NA,"A4",NA,"A7",NA,NA),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to filter the dataset firstly if the `id` is contained in column `upg`. After that, filter out only where column `flag` is 1 (related to `id`)

Expected output should be:

```
id    amount    flag    upg
A4    12        1       NA
```

I tried this:

```
df_example[df_example$id %in% df_example$upg && df_example$flag == 1,]
```

But it returns an empty result.

Please, an answer in base R would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `&&` is used for scalar values i.e when you have single value of `TRUE`/`FALSE`. For comparing vectors you need to use `&`.

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, thank you for the explanation about `&` and `&&`, that's the reason that my code didn't work. I appreciate your time and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help (`&&` uses to work with vectors):

```
df_example[df_example$id %in% df_example$upg & df_example$flag == 1,]
```

Comment: Hello @Duck thank you!, Just a question, do you mean that `&`doesn't work with vectors?

Comment: @Manu Yes, it also works for vectors. But it is preferred to use in a more strict sense such as conditions with vectors inside loops.

Comment: Great answer @Duck, thank you very much! It made me investigate more! Have a great day!

Comment: @Manu Great it helped!If you feel comfortable with the answer, could you just accept it? :)

Comment: Yes I am going to, but the system tells me to wait 2 minutes because it was answered blazingly fast!.